# Expecting to print out an if statement, prints out the else statement instead

Tags: python, if-statement

Basically, I'm writing a program for calculating tournament times to check who won.
I get an error: "Something went wrong. Please try again.".

Here's the code:

```
# This is a Python program intended to calculate which team won,
# using penalties, combined times, and run finish times.


# Ask how many snake laps will happened during the tournament
laps = int(input("How many laps happened? (including the last lap, where the players didn't ride the snake): "))

# Ask for the first team's name
t1name = input("What is the first team's name?: ")
# Ask for the second team's name
t2name = input("What is the second team's name?: ")

# Ask for the first player's name in the first team
t1p1 = input("What is " + t1name + "'s first player named?: ")
# Ask for the second player's name in the first team
t1p2 = input("What is " + t1name + "'s second player named?: ")

# Ask for the first player's name in the second team
t2p1 = input("What is " + t2name + "'s first player named?: ")
# Ask for the second player's name in the second team
t2p2 = input("What is " + t2name + "'s second player named?: ")

# Ask in seconds, how fast the first player of the first team finished in
t1p1finish = int(input("In how many seconds did the first player of the first team finish in?: "))
# Ask in seconds, how fast the second player of the first team finished in
t1p2finish = int(input("In how many seconds did the second player of the first team finish in?: "))

# Ask in seconds, how fast the first player of the second team finished in
t2p1finish = int(input("In how many seconds did the first player of the second team finish in?: "))
# Ask in seconds, how fast the second player of the second team finished in
t2p2finish = int(input("In how many seconds did the second player of the second team finish in?: "))

# Declare what t1finish is
t1finish = int(t1p1finish + t1p2finish)
# Declare what t2finish is
t2finish = int(t2p1finish + t2p2finish)

# Ask what the first team's combined time is
t1time = int(input("What is " + t1name + "'s combined time? (in seconds only): "))
# Ask what the second team's combined time is
t2time = int(input("What is " + t2name + "'s combined time? (in seconds only): "))


# Penalty system
# Penalty if the first team is under 180 seconds, the second team is also
# under 180 seconds, and the second team's combined time is higher than the
# first team's combined time
if t1time > 180 and t2time < t1time and t2time > 180:
    t1pftime = ((t2finish - t1finish) * laps + t1time)
    print(t1pftime)
# Penalty if the first team is under 180 seconds, the second team is also
# under 180 seconds, and the first team's combined time is higher than the
# second team's combined time
elif t1time > 180 and t2time > t1time and t2time > 180:
    t2pftime = ((t1finish - t2finish) * laps + t2time)
    print(t2pftime)

else:
    print("Something went wrong. Please try again.")
```

Here is what I typed in the terminal.

```
$ python goitournament.py 
How many laps happened? (including the last lap, where the players didn't ride the snake): 5
What is the first team's name?: Yeeting
What is the second team's name?: Blasting
What is Yeeting's first player named?: yeet
What is Yeeting's second player named?: adomen
What is Blasting's first player named?: blasbolt
What is Blasting's second player named?: acombo
In how many seconds did the first player of the first team finish in?: 500
In how many seconds did the second player of the first team finish in?: 500
In how many seconds did the first player of the second team finish in?: 500
In how many seconds did the second player of the second team finish in?: 500
What is Yeeting's combined time? (in seconds only): 178
What is Blasting's combined time? (in seconds only): 179
Something went wrong. Please try again.
```

I tried running the code and got a result I didn't expect.
I expected the if statement to work and print out "t1pftime".

This code is not finished, so ignore the names and such.

Comment: Seems likes your class homework

Comment: step 1: remove everything that is not participating in the condition you are testing. Step 2: run that through a debugger

Comment: @EvilReboot it's not.

Comment: @njzk2 alright.

Comment: surely you don't expect that `t1time > 180` is true if you input `t1time = 178`?

Comment: I vote to close as "typo", as it looks like you wanted to test `t1finish > 180` instead

Comment: nope, didn't mean that. I can give you the rules I followed to make this program.

Comment: "-For each second that a team's combined (Glitchless%) PB time is under 3:00, that team will receive a penalty of one second for each second under 3:00 their team
   is per lap."

Comment: @njzk2 that means less than 180. 178 is less than 180

Comment: atleast i'd guess so since the number is on the right

Comment: you might be onto something

Comment: Nevermind, you're right. the symbol was flipped. thanks a bunch!

Comment: There is way too much code here than is needed to replicate your problem. Replace all the calls to `input` with hard-coded values that reproduce the error.

Answer (score 1):

The symbols < and > we're flipped. The code works when I flipped the symbols.

Since the answer I gave in the terminal was 178 (less than 180), and the code did the opposite (if bigger than 180), the else statement was activated.

The code is still wrong, but the issue that was causing the bug I mentioned stopped happening.